# POI: createCellComment: 'Cannot add more than 65535 shapes'

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm trying to clone cell comment.

My code is like:

```
if(cloneFromcell.getCellComment()!=null) {
    Drawing patr = cloneToSheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
    ClientAnchor anchor = patr.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 4);
    Comment comment = patr.createCellComment(anchor);
    comment.setString(new HSSFRichTextString(cloneFromcell.getCellComment().getString().getString()));
    cloneToCell.setCellComment(comment);
}
```

This part might loop hundreds times on each time running the java file, after run the file for several times there will be exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot add more than 65535 shapes
```

on line:

```
Comment comment = patr.createCellComment(anchor);
```

Maybe I should move the create new objects part out of loop? Which part should I move?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using fat32?